# Meaning of 'MAGA gaslights and spins it'

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a tweet talking about Ivanka Trump, @OperativeXRay says

> No matter how MAGA gaslights and spins it, here is proof that Ivanka Trump had a rather cold reception at the UN today:

as quoted in https://popculture.com/trending/2019/09/26/ivanka-trump-blouse-wardrobe-malfunction-united-nations-twitter-talking/

What is the meaning of *MAGA gaslights and spins it*?

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear. What part of the sentence do you not understand? Did you observe that her nipples are visible through the blouse?

Comment: @choster - Judging by the title and concluding question, I'd assume the OP is confused about the verb _gaslights_.

Answer (score 3):

> - [gaslight](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/gaslight)
>     verb
>     to trick or control someone by making them believe things that are not true, especially by suggesting that they may be mentally ill:
>     She had no memory of the incident and thought he was trying to gaslight her.
>     (Cambridge Dictionary)
> - [gaslighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting)
>     Gaslighting is a form of psychological manipulation in which a person seeks to sow seeds of doubt in a targeted individual or in members of a targeted group, making them question their own memory, perception, and sanity. Using persistent denial, misdirection, contradiction, and lying, gaslighting involves attempts to destabilize the victim and delegitimize the victim's belief.
>     (Wikipedia)
> - [spin](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/spin)
>     verb
>     to apply a slant or particular emphasis to (information), as to persuade or deceive
>     (Collins Dictionary)

MAGA, which stands for “Make America Great Again”, has come to represent the sphere of Donald Trump supporters. We don’t know what the first “it” refers to until the end of the sentence. We then understand that “it” is the situation, the mishap, or the reception. We can roughly rephrase the sentence as

> No matter how Trump supporters lie about, deny, slant, or misrepresent the mishap, here is proof that Ivanka Trump had a rather cold reception at the UN today:

That last bit is a pun, as cold temperature causes one’s nipples to harden, but a cold reception is an unfriendly one.

Comment: This is really nicely written: "No matter how ... supporters lie about, deny, slant, or misrepresent the mishap".

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was a little wordy. :)